# HTML <br/> tag breaks <code> segments?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page with some `<code>` segments, and I have given them these attributes in an external CSS folder:

```
code {

    background-color: f5f5ff;
    border-color : 7f7fbf;
    border-style : dashed;
    border-width : 1px;
    font-family  : courier new;
    margin-left  : 128px;
    padding      : 14px;
}
```

Whenever I put a `<br/>` in my code segments, the code seems to jump to the left, ignoring the margin, and the padding covers the last line, like it was a whole new `<code>` segment placed directly below it, down to about where the padding would end, and without a left margin.

How do I make a `<code>` segment with line breaks that displays all the code in a single 'box', line breaks and all, until the end of the `<code>` segment, like it is being displayed in the `<code>` segments in the preview of my post right now?

Here's an example of one of my `<code>` blocks/segments:

```
import math<br/>
def areaCircle(r)<br/>
return (math.pi * r) ^ 2
```

Unfortunately, I cannot provide a picture because I am a very new user.

I have tested this in both Chrome and FireFox; the problem is exactly the same in both browsers.

Comment: Haha, good luck editing this `<code>` question into `<br />` shape `<br />` :)

Comment: Thanks for the effort put into formatting this question, but it's actually can be done much easier. I'm not entirely sure I got it right so you might want to revise my edit for unwanted tags.

Comment: If you can't post images to StackOverflow, post it to a image-sharing site like http://tinypic.com/ and tell us the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off not adding `<br />` and using `white-space: pre` and `display: block` on the `code` element.

```
code {
   display: block;
   white-space: pre;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Bw3bd/).

Answer (score 3):

`<pre>` tags should be the tag of your choice, not `<code>` blocks, which should be inline.

Note: `<pre>` block *do* care about whitespace, so make sure to not contain extra whitespace.

Compare:

```html
<pre>
import math
def areaCircle(r)
return (math.pi * r) ^ 2
</pre>
```

To:

```html
    <pre><!-- Extra whitespace generated -->
    import math
    def areaCircle(r)
    return (math.pi * r) ^ 2
    </pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `<pre>` for your task: http://jsfiddle.net/qSfGQ/5/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you shouldn't even need the `<br />` tags if you're only wanting to show code snippets with correct line breaks.